# Connect to Meteor using Robomongo

Tags: meteor, robo3t

I have Meteor running on a local virtual machine on Windows which is accessible using the IP address of 192.168.56.111

When I use Robomongo, I use this IP address and point it to port 3001 and I an unable to connect.

Should I expect it to connect? If not, is there anything I need to do to get it to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Setup SSH server on Windows](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/set-up-a-windows-ssh-tunnel-in-10-minutes-or-less/) and then simply create SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L27018:192.168.56.111:3001 user@host
```

After that open Robomongo and connect to localhost:27018. That's it!

This technique I'm using successfully to connect to production database.

Answer (score 2):

With meteor the database that runs is bound to 127.0.0.1, so it will not be accessible on other IPs. I think this was done for a security reason, though not sure.

You should use the local IP/127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.56.11.